# Google API PHP Client with the Admin SDK - listUsers returns "Invalid Input"

Tags: google-api-php-client

I am trying to use the Google_Service_Directory to listUsers() and cannot determine what why "Invalid Input" is the error returned.

```
<?php
require_once("autoload.php");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("G Suite");
$client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"));
$client->setAuthConfig(json_decode($json_credentials,true));
$service = new Google_Service_Directory($client);
$results = $service->users->listUsers(array("customer"=>"my_customer"));
?>
```

Results:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Input"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Input"
 }
}
```